# AngularJS modulerr when placed inside promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS nOOb here. I have a function that fetches data from DynamoDB. Results from this function needs to be populated in to a HTML SELECT list.

Here's relevant HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
 <div ng-controller="myctrl">
  <select ng-model="roadname" ng-options="x for x in roadNames"></select>           
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's relevant failure JS:

```
var function_AWS_get = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(get_result_array);
 } // End of Function

// Call the Function with promise and populate data in to the FORMs
function_AWS_get.then( function(result) {
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
  app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {   
    $scope.roadNames = result;  
   });
 }, function(err) {
     $scope.roadNames = ["Error"];
   });
```

If I move the angular app controller to outside the promise function, then there is no error and the form contents get populated:

This is working JS:

```
var function_AWS_get = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(get_result_array);
 } // End of Function

// Call the Function with promise. But, move angular code outside the promise
function_AWS_get.then( function(result) {
 }, function(err) {
      $scope.roadNames = ["Error"];
  });

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
   app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {   
   $scope.roadNames = ["Success"];  
 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
   app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {   
   $scope.roadNames = ["Success"];  
 });
```

You have to keep your angular module outside all functions .This is the initiating point of your and it shouldn't be inside any promise /functions

Inside the controller make the ajax call and render your results

Comment: Good answer. One more not for @Anand: Not sure if you simplified the code for this question. But it is best practice to put the app, ctrl and services (your AWS_get function) in separate files.

Comment: Thanks @Piyush.kapoor. How can I ensure my angular controller sets value only after it receives results from another function?

Comment: In your angular controller you can initiate a http call
$http.get('/files/hhh').then(function(response) {
//set scope value here
$scope.roadNames = response
});

you can check the syntax online its very simple $http is the method

Comment: In this case,the data is not a http source, its from DynamoDB. I am now trying to insert the AWS promise inside the angular controller and it works. This is my updated code:

    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
      app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {   
      $scope.roadNames = ["Loading..."];
         function_AWS_get.then( function(result) {
            $scope.roadNames = result;
            }, function(err) {           
           });
    });

This now (somewhat) works but fetches content only after the SELECT box has been accessed once

Answer (score 0):

In this cases you want to bootstrap application manually with [`angular.bootstrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) method:

```
// Call the Function with promise and populate data in to the FORMs
function_AWS_get
  .catch(function() {
    return ["Error"];
  })
  .then(function(result) {

    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.roadNames = result;
    });

    // Bootstrap the app
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#myapp'), [app.name])
  });
```

Check the simple demo below.

```js
var get_result_array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
var function_AWS_get = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(get_result_array);
});

// Call the Function with promise and populate data in to the FORMs
function_AWS_get
  .catch(function() {
    return ["Error"]
  })
  .then(function(result) {

    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.roadNames = result;
    });

    // Bootstrap the app
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#myapp'), [app.name])
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <select ng-model="roadname" ng-options="x for x in roadNames"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to register angular controller inside .then you will never have access to response object and this is the reason $scope.roadNames is not getting initialized. And also this is the best practice to register all your controllers/services/directives outside all functions.
And always write angular service and put the code there which is responsible to interact with server.

You can use the below code:

### Service.js

```
app.service('MyService', function() {
  var function_AWS_get = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(get_result_array);
  };

  this.getRoadNames = function(successHandler, failureHandler) {
    function_AWS_get.then( function(result) {
       successHandler(result);  
    }, function(err) {
       failureHandler(err);
    }); 

  };
});
```

### Controller

```
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, MyService) {   
   function fetchRoadlistSuccessHandler(response) {
     $scope.roadNames = response; 
   }

   function fetchRoadlistFailureHandler(err) {
     $scope.roadNames = err;
   }

   MyService.getRoadNames(fetchRoadlistSuccessHandler, fetchRoadlistFailureHandler);  
 });
```